# Removing Special Characters in CSV using PostgreSQL

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, sql-delete

I am trying to remove multiple special characters in a CSV file that I am copying into a created table in Postgresql. I have about 4CSV files like this, with 100,000 rows and 10 columns. I am getting errors every few 50-100 rows and I don't know what all the special characters are, as this is a large data set. Is there anyway I can just delete these or create something in excel/csv to delete these? I am afraid that I will be deleting important data

What would be best code?

Thanks!

Brook

Comment: What is your db server char encoding? client encoding? csv file encoding?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? When loading how, with what command? Details please!

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks guys!

Comment: How do I give you guys votes or points?